# What are some physical applications of rectangular aperture Fraunhofer diffraction?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, diffraction

**I have first provided a simple explanation of Fraunhofer diffraction for rectangular aperture, feel free to skip this entire quoted section to the question below if you already know about the topic.**

> Far field light incident on a rectangular aperture leads to the
> formation of a diffraction pattern that is a straightforward extension
> of a single slit diffraction. In that there there are 2 single slit
> patterns orthogonal to one another. This can be illustrated by the
> following diagram.
>
> [image]
>
> An example of the diffraction pattern obtained is as follows
>
> [image]
>
> The relation of intensity of the diffraction pattern to x, y
> co-ordinates of the observation plane is given by the formula.
>
> $$I(x,y) \propto sinc^{2} \left ( \frac{\pi Wx}{\lambda \sqrt{x^2+L^2}} \right ) sinc^{2} \left ( \frac{\pi Hy}{\lambda \sqrt{y^2+L^2}} \right )$$
> Where $\text{sinc}(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$, $W$ is the aperture width, $H$ is the aperture height, $\lambda$ is the wavelength, $L$ is the aperture-to-image distance, and $x$ and $y$ are the observation plane coordinates.

My question is as follows.

**What are a few examples of the real life applications/implications of fraunhofer diffraction for rectangular aperture in particular?**

I need to include a few examples of real life applications for a physics project and I was unable to find any clear sources online.

I suspect is that rectangular apertures must be used for telescopes but searching online I can only find telescopes using circular apertures. As a side question, what is the practical reason for this, are circular apertures inherently better? Do circular apertures make for clearer images?

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: I believe that some radar systems for aircraft detection use rectangular arrays of antennae; that would be an example of a rectangular aperture. Also some of the radio antenna arrays used for astronomy might be rectangular.

Comment: Thanks I'll check this out.